# Place text on image at specific locations

Tags: graphics, backgrounds, eso-pic

I am trying to palace text on a background image for a cover for a document.  The background image will be static hence I used `\AddToShipoutPicture*`

I would like to know if there is a much more efficient method to place the text on the background cover image.

This is the code that I currently have:

```
\documentclass[11pt,openany]{book}

\usepackage{etex}
\reserveinserts{28}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating, ltablex, dcolumn, booktabs}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

%======================================================================================
%   TITLE PAGE
%======================================================================================
\begingroup

\frontmatter

\thispagestyle{empty}

\AddToShipoutPicture*{\put(-8,-2.5){\includegraphics[scale=5]{example-image-a}}
\put(30,50){\Huge\textcolor{white}{Advanced Data Mining}}
\put(30,500){\Huge\textcolor{white}{This is some other text}}
\put(500,100){\rotatebox{90}{\Huge\textcolor{white}{This is some other text}}}
\put(530,100){\rotatebox{90}{\Huge\textcolor{white}{This is some more added text}}}
\put(200,270){\Huge\textcolor{white}{This is some other text}}
\put(200,240){\Huge\textcolor{white}{And some more}}
\put(200,210){\Huge\textcolor{white}{And even more}}

}
\mbox{~}
\clearpage
\newpage

\endgroup


%========================================================================================
%   MAINMATTER
%========================================================================================
\mainmatter

\chapter{Default chapter layout}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `overpic`package could have helped you to find the coordinates. As an alternative, you could place the text with tikz. This would allow you to place things relative to the various locations on the page.

Comment: Related? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz

Comment: Maybe you wnat take a look to the packages background or wallpaper, and then place the text over as in a page without images.